# If you are given the ratios of the angles of a triangle, how do you find the degrees?

Tags: geometry, triangles

If  you are given the ratios of the angles of a triangle, how do you find the degrees?

Please use basic geometry as this is a question my 9th-grade daughter had for me.

Comment: Can’t you just use a final equation by stating that the sum of the angles is $180^°$?

Comment: @Mindlack  I could, but I have forgotten so much math in the 40+ years since I last had a math class. :) I found the answer and posted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you all. I found the answer.

If it were a ratio of 3:6:1, this can be solved by 3x+6x+1x=180, and simply solve for x.

Answer (score 1):

With mid-school tools, very simply:

If, say, $\:(\alpha:\beta:\gamma)=(3:4:5)$, then

$$\frac\alpha3=\frac\beta4=\frac\gamma 5=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{3+4+5}=\frac{180}{12}=15.$$